# Creating multiple symlink on loop causes unstable behaviour

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've been trying to create symlinks of 8 different products in a single Ansible task. Here is my code.

```
- name: Other symlinks of Products
  file:
    src: "/var/www/html/{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/{{release_folder}}/{{ item.dest }}"
    state: link
  with_items:
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p1
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p2
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p3
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p4
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p5
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p6
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p7
  - src:  simpleRepo
    dest:  p8
```

Error:

> (item={u'dest': u'p3', u'src': u'simpleRepo'}) => {"failed": true, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "item": {"dest": "p3", "src": "simpleRepo"}, "mode": "0755", "msg": "refusing to convert between directory and link for /var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/20161214-2004/p3", "owner": "root", "path": "/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/20161214-2004/p3", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 0}

Error 2

> failed: [54.85.157.222] (item={u'dest': u'p8', u'src': u'simpleRepo'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"dest": "p8", "src": "simpleRepo"}, "msg": "Error while linking: [Errno 2] No such file or directory", "path": "/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/20161214-2005/p8", "state": "absent"}

And here are the contents list `/var/www/html/simpleRepo` has just `index.html` and `/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/` has release folder based on timestmp `20161214-1922 , 20161214-1921`,  `/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/20161214-1922/` should have `p1, p2` symlinks which point to `p1 -> /var/www/html/simpleRepo`

I tried creating all the folders first and symlinking `simpleRepo`. Also, i used the `command` module, changed the directory. Like this. Still, creating symlink is unstable.

```
 - command: ln -s /var/www/html/simpleRepo /var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/{{release_folder}}/p2
   args:
     chdir: /var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/{{release_folder}}/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And here are the contents, also updated the question by including the Ansible transcript
`/var/www/html/simpleRepo` has just `index.html` and 
`/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/` has release folder based on timestmp `20161214-1922` , `20161214-1921`
and `/var/www/html/simpleRepoTwo/simpleRepoThree/20161214-1922/` should have `productOne`, `productTwo` symlinks  which point to `productOne -> /var/www/html/simpleRepo`

Comment: @techraf, yes, all the directories are present.

Comment: Hello, techraf, thanks for pointing out. I've corrected the mistakes, included task and contents. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Hello, techraf, thanks for not answering. I figured the solution. The problem was on creating folder based on timestamp. On change of timestamp, different folders would create. Hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, I got the same error message:

```
refusing to convert between directory and link for /path/to/file
```

Because an earlier task in my playbook had created a directory with the same name as the link that I was trying to create in `dest`.

Comment: So, how do you finally fix it? I'm facing the same issue, first I create the directories and then the symbolic links and I'm not able to fix it

Comment: @Ferran - if there is an existing item with the same name (e.g. a directory) then it is not possible to create a link with the same name as the existing name. If this applies to you then the solution is either to remove the existing item, or to create your link with a different name.